# Align image inside div to right

Tags: html, css

I have `div` which has smaller width than image inside it and `div` has set overflow to hidden. So the image is visible only some part from the left.

I want to see that image some part but from right.

**html**

```
<div id="my_div">
    <img src="some_image.jpg" width="600" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#my_div {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So I see only 50% of that image from left. I want to see 50% of that image from right. I dont want to see whole image. How can be done this?

**EDIT**

I cant set CSS:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: You can set float:right property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1:

float the img to the right

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bz52nmkw/2/)

```css
#my_div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#my_div img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" width="600" />
</div>
```

### Solution #2:

Set `direction: rtl;` on the container

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bz52nmkw/1/)

```css
#my_div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" width="600" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#my_div {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#my_div img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

**Second Solution**
you may also do this

```
#my_div {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#my_div img{
    float:right;
}
```

It is working fine, but i still dont understand why are you using an image what you dont want to see on the website. Why dont you just crop it? :)

Comment: See my edit, I cant use `position: absolute;`, that I know. Its because of 2 version of website, one is full functional and second is new, which is on testing. It must work on old design and also in new, and I need to see right part of that image.

Answer (score 1):

What about `float:right;` property? Thanks to hidden overflow, you can see only the right part of the image.

```
#my_div img {
    float:right;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/499nhjb0/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent div a relative position.
And wrap the image in a child div and make that absolute.

**HTML**

```
<div id="my_div">
<img src="some_image.jpg" width="600" height="300" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#my_div {
    height:300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#my_div img{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2743pe3/2/)

Comment: @Legionar I've updated it. It works now without changing HTML

Comment: Thanks, but please see my question, I cant use position absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for solving this problem

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/skart/q0rqwew3/2/)

Comment: Thank you, thats another solution :-)